# IntelliJ runs maven goals under root credentials

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu

I use IntelliJ under Ubuntu.
When I run a maven goal using the plugin in IntelliJ I see that the process is started under the credentials of a root user. This is not what I want.

When I start the proces from a bash shell using mvn clean install the process is started under my own credentials. This is what I want and what you would expect.

Since I want to run maven goals using my IDE under my own credentials I am wandering what I am doing wrong.

Comment: How do you see that?

Comment: The owner of the newly created target directory is root. Also if I do a ps - ef | grep root I find that the maven process is started under root credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably run IntelliJ as root. Check it using `ps aux | grep intellij | grep root.`

Comment: That is what I thought.  But it is not the case. I start my intelliJ  from a bash shell under my own credentials. If I create a Java source file it is created under these credentials as one would expect. Perhaps I should reinstall my intelliJ.

Comment: In run view in Idea you can see the command and output of run Maven goal like: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Dmaven.home=/home/arkonix/programs/intellij/idea...` maybe this might provide some insight into your problem.

Answer (score 0):

After a week of struggling with the problem I finally saw the light.
In IntelliJ the Maven setting pointed to another Java install directory then the $JAVA_HOME.
When inspecting the two java executables I saw that the uuid bit of the java executable used by IntelliJ was set.
Thus everything created was created under the credentials of root and not the credentials under which intelliJ was started.

ls -al:
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root   7734 jun 11 11:20 java